# Javascript async return

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsf, customdialog

I'm using JSF ajax ( we can NOT change that =\ ) in my application and we need to wait for action from the user. I mean, before call the ajax method, i need ask to the user if he wants to revert all the changes in the page using custom dialog. If he wants to go ahead and revert I will call the Java method by ajax and ok, but if not we dont need to call the ajax.

Let me try be more specific:

This is a code for the revert button for my huge page:

```
<h:commandButton value="#{msg.revertBtn}" accesskey="R" styleClass="actionButton" action="#{styleController.revertChanges}">

    <f:ajax execute="@this" onstart="return method();" render="styleCcFormtyleCcTable">

</h:commandButton>
```

Before calling the ajax it will run my javascript function: `method()`

I need have the user stuck in `method()` until he clicks in `Yes` or `Now` button in my custom confirm dialog and then return true or false.

Any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know some of you guys wont agree with me, because I did a huge workaround to have it working.

What I did was:

I created a Custom Confirm Dialog and it has a variable which store the user reply. Then, whenever the user clicks on the button it will be stored there.

So, in the button I added an click function that checks my variable and if it has any reply it goes and do something but it not I call my custom dialog.

And into my custom dialog I am "clicking" in the button, but now with the reply. After that you need to make sure you will erase the variable.

Just that. 2 days doing that o.O Let me know if you guys need the code for that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to hook on the button's `onclick` handler instead in order to be able to block button's default action by returning `true` or `false` accordingly in there. Once the ajax request is been executed, it's namely already too late to block it.

Here's a kickoff example using JavaScript's builtin [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.confirm) function.

```html
<h:commandButton ... onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="styleCcFormtyleCcTable" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: seems better but i need to use my own confirm dialog. Is there any way to call the click method and do something like: 

<script>if ( customDialog.reply === "YES" ){ button.click() }</script>
and button.click check if I already clicked and call the ajax?
It seems a workaround but I will have it working what is the priority for now. Thanks